# Transition between size when parent div of child element changes

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a menu that becomes a fixed menu when scrolling down the website. When that happens, the class `r-header-fixed` is added (and removed when scrolling back up). The logo that is inside my fixed menu is smaller than the one you see on pageload but when I scroll the size instantly changes. How can I ease the transition?

This is my css line:

```
.r-header-fixed .container .row .col-md-3 .r-logo .d-inline-block .logomurrays{
  height:70px;
}
```

I tried adding `transition: height 4s;` to that, but the change is still instant.

Comment: The logo must have a starting point for `height` property in px or any other measuring unit, but it can't transition from auto.

Comment: This can be solved by many ways. Check this https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

Comment: `transition' needs a 3rd parameter: 'ease' or 'ease-in-out', etc...

Comment: @RenevanderLende, that's not accurate. Initial value of [`transition-timing-function`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#transition-timing-function-property) is `ease`

Comment: @twan, your question is not answerable without a [mcve].